# Is it bad to start a sentence with "as"?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-starts

My boss doesn't like it when I start sentences with "as", and I'm not sure if it's actually a problem.

A case where I would start with "as" would be:

> As your new account manager, it is my responsibility to . . .

Comment: As I see it, **no**. However, arguing with your boss is usually a poor way to advance in your career.

Comment: As you are asked to do so, you might try formulations such as "Taking into account the supposedly well-known fact that I am the new account manager, all in this room should doubtlessly agree that it is my repsonsibility to ..." and see who is still awake when you've completed it. ;)

Answer (score 16):

Starting a sentence with *as* is not a problem, and never was. The Corpus of Contemporary American English has 150000+ cites for sentences starting with *as*, across all registers and contexts, including academic writing. Your boss is completely alone in this.

However, what your boss might *actually* be objecting to is the so-called [dangling modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier). Prescriptive approach dictates that what you are really saying in that sentence is that the manager is not yourself, but the responsibility. However, from a descriptivist's standpoint, that is a perfectly natural, grammatical construction that is widely used and understood.

Comment: +1. I was about to say more or less the same, but was distracted by a telephone call.

Comment: +1 for dangling modifier. "As your new account manager, I have the responsibility to..."

Comment: Make your boss happy with "I have the responsibility (as your new account manager) to..."